# Replace nth occurence of string in each line of a text without extra software

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text, cmd

I want to replace the third tabkey on each row, and replace it with a colon.
Is this possible in windows through cmd? I am doing this with large text files that are too big for notepad++ and I want to refrain from installing extra software if possible

input

user    namefirst namelast  email   number

output

user    namefirst namelast  email:number

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing sample text. If it's three tabs in a row, yes. Otherwise it's going to be really hard (I've never tried to do something like this, but it's possible in theory).

Comment: You could just open your tab delimited data in Excel then use the solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/387373/merging-columns-in-excel-with-separator).

Comment: It is too large for excel, and breaking the files up all the time would be a pain

Comment: If it's too large for Excel, it's _way_ too big for batch.

Comment: What do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Please edit the question and provide three (3) (at least one (1)) records from the existing file and the desired output. This does not sound too difficult.

Comment: I added desired output and input. first and last name are separated by a space (so it should consider the name as 1 column), everything else is separated by tab. Keep in mind the script should run for multiple rows

Comment: This should work: `(for /F "tokens=1-5" %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%a %%b %%c %%d:%%e) > output.txt`. Just be sure to insert the proper separators after the `echo` command, that is, a TAB after `%%a` and `%%c`, and a space after `%%b`.

Comment: Do I need to I need 5 letter's if there is only 4 [tab] columns, just one has a [space] in it

Comment: sometimes it will be just firstname, other times it will be firstname[space]lastname. But it should always be treated as one column

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this? Your code works, but it treats spaces as columns too

Comment: _"sometimes it will be just firstname, other times it will be firstname[space]lastname"_ This is the type of details that nobody could know if you don't tell us... **`:(`**  See my answer below (and reread lit's comment above)

Answer (score 0):

Since batch file for loops process one line at a time the file size shouldn't matter. It may take a while to run but it should complete.

Test data in TestInput.txt:

```
one two three   four    five six seven
1   2   3   4   5 6 7
only    two tabs in this line
only    one tab in this line
no tabs in this line
this    line    has 5   tabs    in it
```

Batch files uses TestInput.txt

```
@echo off
if exist TestOutput.txt del TestOutput.txt
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,* delims=^T" %%A in (TestInput.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,* delims=    " %%A in (TestInput.txt) do (
if not "%%D"=="" (
    rem The line has at least 3 tabs

    rem OutputLine=%%A^T%%B^T%%C:%%D^T%%E
    set OutputLine=%%A  %%B %%C:%%D %%E
) else (
    if not "%%C"=="" (
        rem line has 2 tabs
        rem OutputLine=%%A^T%%B^T%%C%%D%%E
        set OutputLine=%%A  %%B %%C%%D%%E
    ) else (
        if not "%%B"=="" (
            rem line has 1 tab
            rem OutputLine=%%A^T%%B%%C%%D%%E
            set OutputLine=%%A  %%B%%C%%D%%E
        ) else (
            rem line has no tabs
            set OutputLine=%%A%%B%%C%%D%%E
        )
    )
)
echo !OutputLine!
echo !OutputLine!>>TestOutput.txt
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
exit
```

Note that the character after the delims= is an actual tab character. Make sure your editor does not replace tabs with spaces or use Notepad.exe for the editor.

I'm not sure how the forum posts save the data but the character between %%A and %%B, %%B and %%C, and %%C and %%D must be an actual tab character also.

Comment: when I ran it, the output was the exact same as the input

Comment: Yet looking at your code, it seems as though it's supposed to do what I requested on the thread

Comment: I copied and pasted the posted code into a .bat file and ran it. It performed as expected. What are you calling a "tabkey"? This code uses the character output when you press the [tab] key on the keyboard. My bad. Although I wrote the code in Notepad, it replaces the [tab] characters with spaces when when doing a copy and paste. I modified the code above with remarks to show where the tabs go. Change your code to ensure actual tab characters are in the places where the ^T is in the comments and delete in spaces in those locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
(for /F "tokens=1-5" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%e" neq "" (
      echo %%a  %%b %%c %%d:%%e
   ) else (
      echo %%a  %%b %%c:%%d
   )
)) > output.txt
```

Just be sure to insert the proper separators in `echo` command in each case: a TAB after `%%a` and `%%c` and a space after `%%b` in first case; or a TAB after `%%a` and `%%b` in second case...